# Codeigniter Insert into Many-to-Many Joining Table/Pivot Table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, many-to-many

I apologise if this has been answered previously (and would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me to it), but how would I go about inserting into a many-to-many join table?

Essentially I have a contest based on sports events, and hence have a join table to match the contest_id to the relevant sports_events_id . If I were to create a new contest, how would I also insert into the join table database simultaneously?

Or, would I have to create the contest first to get the contest_id, and then (and only then) insert into the joining table all the relevant sports_events_id?

I appreciate any assistance and advice you could provide.

Many thanks.

**Solution**

Ok so I've now got the following solution to insert into the joining table

**Controller**

```
function add()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contest_name', 'Contest Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $data['view_file'] = 'add_contest';
            $this->load->module('template');
            $this->template->cmslayout($data);

        } else {

            $data1 = array(
                'contest_name' => $this->input->post('contest_name'),
            );

            $data2 = $this->input->post('game');

            if ($this->_transactions_new_contest($data1, $data2)) {
                return $query;
            }
            redirect('/contests/');
        }
    }

function _transactions_new_contest($data1, $data2) {
    $this->load->model('mdl_contests');
    $this->mdl_contests->_transactions_new_contest($data1, $data2);
}
```

**Model**

```
function _transactions_new_contest($data1, $data2){
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('contests', $data1);
    $contest_id = $this->db->query('SELECT contests.id FROM contests ORDER BY contests.id DESC limit 1');
    foreach ($contest_id->result() as $row) {
        $contest_result_id = $row->id;
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO contests_has_sports_events (contests_id, sports_events_id) VALUES (' . $contest_result_id . ', ' . $data2 . ')');
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

Now the problem is, how do I now loop the $data2 if I have multiple sports_events_id or post('game')?

Once again, if you could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean a pivot table by join table? If you do, you don't really need a pivot table in this particular case. Just use foreign key contraints.

Comment: Yes, of course. That totally missed my mind. Would this simply be like a foreach loop where every entry inserted (within the same contest) would have different id and sports_events_id but the the same foreign constraint id? Performance wise, which would be more recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you would need to first insert into parent tables and then insert into dependent tables using the parent table ID as a foreign key reference in the dependent table.

What you are actually hinting are **transactions**. A database transaction allows you to insert, update, delete rows in different tables atomically: Either they all work and are committed, or if one fails they all rollback so you maintain data integrity.

CodeIgniter supports [transactions](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html).

Comment: Ahh excellent, thank you for the answer. That's exactly what I need. Now would the queries I put inside the transactions occur in the order I put them in, or would this have to be managed another way?

Comment: @RyanN.You write your queries in the order you want them to execute inside the transaction block.

Comment: Thanks mate. You've been very helpful!